# ¿Cómo copiar información existente de una tabla a otra?

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, postgresql

Tengo una base de datos realizada en `postgresql`, y tengo una tabla llamada "compromisos", la cual contiene información, sin embargo por cuestiones de seguridad necesito realizar una copia de esa tabla a otra llamada "CompromisosPag", la cual contiene la misma estructura de la tabla "Compromisos" solo que guarda la copia. Este proceso de copia se realiza a través de un botón que tengo en mi vista realizada en codeignater, entonces básicamente al pulsar ese botón se debe generar una el proceso de copia de la tabla compromiso hacia la tabla "CompromisosPag", entonces ¿ cómo puedo hacer esa copia?, ¿Me recomiendan usar alguna vista?, mi tabla es la siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Nos muestras que has intentado por favor?

Comment: Hola Alberto, puedes enseñarnos que funcionalidad tienes ya hecha con el boton para realizar el proceso de copia

Comment: Aún no he programado el botón, porque quedé atascado pensando en como realizar la copia, estaba pensando crear una sentencia sql que realice el proceso, pero no busque la forma de realizarla

Comment: no sé si emplear algo como esto estaría bien:INSERT INTO tablaDestino 
SELECT * FROM tablaOrigen, porque igual la tabla compromisos tiene llaves foráneas

Comment: Inténtalo así como pusiste, y si tienes algún problema en concreto lo publicas y te echamos la mano.

Answer (score 0):

No se mucho de postgressql pero una idea seria

```
truncate table CompromisoPag;
insert into CompromisoPag select * from Compromiso;
```

ya puedes crear un sp con esa instruccion